# Verificar se data é par ou ímpar

Tags: sql, data

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com datas no SQL Server.

Tenho uma campo data e gostaria de saber se está data é impar ou par.
Pois preciso fazer está comparação para usar em outro campo. Procurei alguns métodos mas não cheguei na solução. Pensei em usar o DATEDIFF mas não tenho outro campo de data para comparar.

```
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(DATE,data_saida)) IN (3) AND porto = 409 
THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(DAY, -2, CONVERT(DATE,data_saida))) + ' TO ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, data_saida)))
```

Esse código eu uso que essa entrega é somente na terça-feira. Não estou levando em consideração se data_saida é ímpar ou par. Agora surgiu essa demanda de última hora e não sei onde encaixar corretamente.

Comment: Pode descrever o que é uma "data par"?

Comment: _30_ de qualquer mês/ano é uma data par? a validação seria apenas no dia do mês??

Comment: Perdão a falta de informação. Gostaria de saber se na data completa (DD/MM/YYYY) o DD é par ou impar. Por exemplo hoje 14/12/2018 (14 > par). Essas datas que tenho são dentro do mês atual.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o operador `%` (mod) para saber se a data é par ou ímpar.

Se o resto da divisão do dia por 2 for igual a 0 então temos um número par, caso contrário ele é ímpar.

Exemplo para SQL Server:

```
SELECT CASE DAY(data_saida) % 2 WHEN 0
            THEN 'PAR'
       ELSE 'IMPAR'
        END
```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro.
Eu tenho um campo data já predefinido (vou deixar o código) e não posso utilizar o getdate. Pois as datas já definidas representam a saída de produtos das transportadoras. Porém, se as datas de saída forem par eles entregam somente de x a y e impar de x a z, por exemplo. Vou editar acima.

Comment: Alterei a resposta para utilizar a `data_saida`, agora é só implementar a lógica no lugar do 'PAR' e 'IMPAR'

Comment: Caro Pedro, estou tentando aplicar a regra em meu case mas não tenho sucesso. Conforme meu case acima, estou utilizando desta forma:
`WHEN DATEPART(DW, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),data_saida,103)%2 WHEN 0) IN (3) AND porto = 409   
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),data_saida,103)
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),data_saida,103) `
Eu estou utilizando `datepart` para setar os dias da semana que irão ocorrer as entregas. Entendo que já me deu uma luz, mas teria alguma alternativa a isso ou estou fazendo da forma incorreta?

Comment: O dw está fazendo o papel para eu informar que os dias da semana, por exemplo: nas datas (data_saida) que cair 1,2,3,4 (segunda, terça, quarta e quinta) a coleta deverá ser feita de x a y dias. Porém agora quero informar que se a data_saida (dd/mm/yyyy) além de cair em 1,2,3,4  e for ímpar será em outros dias e segue o mesmo para par. Essa data_saida é mensal, no caso o mês atual.
Não sei se deu para entender bem, mas no geral é: se a data_saida cair em uma sexta-feira (14/12/2018) é par, então a data de coleta terá que ser de segunda a quinta e se impar segue outra regra.